# How to split column value containing multiple strings in multiple rows?

Tags: matlab

```
%INPUT
table = {1 'A,B'; 2 'C,D,E'};
for i = 1:length(table)
separated_list{i,1} = strsplit(table{i,2});
end

%OUTPUT
separated_list = {1x2 cell; 1x3 cell}
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve in matlab:

**ID VAL**

1 A,B

2 C,D ,F

**TGT**

ID VAL

1 A

1 B

2 C

2 D

2 F

I have been trying to use strplit function in a for loop in matlab, but it is not getting me to to the final result as I would like it to be. Any hints would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: cell array of characters.

Comment: table = {1 'A,B'; 2 'C,D,F'}


for i = 1:length(table)

    separated_reqs{i,1} = strsplit(table{i,2});

end

Comment: Output: 

separated_reqs = {1x2 cell; 1x3 cell}

Sorry I am having trouble presenting the code in a readable format.